# try download a file from server if the pathname is known

Tags: networking, wget, http

I access a webpage by this url

`http://someRandomName.no.meaning:20025/hello.html`

The location of the `hello.html` that is displayed is `/var/some/fulder/hello.html`. (I mean in the server it is `/var/some/fulder/hello.html`)

I also know a file in the server which is at location `/home/someuser/somefolder/movie.mp4`.

How can I try to download this file? Can I use `wget` or any other utility/tool to try to download it (copy it to my computer)?

If file has read access to everyone then maybe I can try to download it.  I tried using

```
`$ wget http://someRandomName.no.meaning:20025/../../../home/someuser/somefolder/movie.mp4`
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because any sanely implemented web server will not allow you to download just any file on the server.  Even if you're really clever and use `../../../`

If the file is not in one of the directories that it is configured to allow access to (e.g. the `DocumentRoot` or `/home/*/public_html`) then it will not (and should not) allow anyone to download it.  Note that not all web servers are configured to serve user home pages from ~/public_html.

If the file is yours, in your home directory, try making a directory called `~/public_html` and copying, moving, or symlink-ing the file into it (note that webservers are sometimes configured to not follow symlinks)

on server:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir public_html
$ mv movie.mp4 public_html/
```

on client machine:

```
wget http://someRandomName.no.meaning:20025/~username/movie.mp4
```

Comment: thanks for the info. this is a challenge in security course, so there is a vulnerability which i have to exploit .. so the web server may not be sanitizing the inputs ... but my problem is `../../../` is removed in the shell itslef , i.e. `wget url/../../../path/to/file` becomes `wget url/path/to/file` in my shell itself ...

Comment: @drewbenn, how does that help?  telnetting to the web server port doesn't do anything that wget or curl or LWP's GET or HEAD or a thousand other web-fetcher tools do.

Comment: well, that makes perfect sense.  do something really awkward and tedious rather than figure out how i'm mistyping my wget command and fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Web servers are configured to serve only files from within a certain directory.

For example, Apache has `DocumentRoot`, which in your example would be set to `/var/some/fulder`.  Something similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:20025>
        ServerAlias someRandomName.no.meaning
        DocumentRoot /var/some/fulder
</VirtualHost>
```

This will serve the content of the Document Root directory at `http://someRandomName.no.meaning:20025`.  Any directory below the Document Root would be accessible through the URL with the directory name appended, so that `/var/some/fulder/stuff` would be accessible at `http://someRandomName.no.meaning:20025/stuff`.

A html page within `stuff` could use `../hello.html` to reference the file at the Document Root (as this is still within the Document Root) but it cannot *escape* from this root by using `../../<anything here>`.

Think about it - what a major security issue this would be if it was possible.  A hacker would have access to *all* files on *all* web servers.

Comment: thank you for the info. This is actually a challenge in a security course, so the web server admin has deliberately left a vulnerability...